# How to load a TypeScript error log file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Is it possible to load a error log file in VSCode?
After piping errors to a file `tsc > tsc.log` I would like to load the log file and work through the errors in all project files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be surprised if there's anything built-in for this. However, you can easily trick VSCode into "loading the file into the problems panel" by running a task that outputs the file contents and applies the TypeScript problem matcher to that output.

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Load tsc.log",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "type",
            "args": ["tsc.log"],
            "problemMatcher": ["$tsc"]
        }
    ]
}
```

(replace the `type` command with `cat` if you're not using Windows)

---

Note that the `$tsc` problem matcher [is only applied to closed files](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/9878edb2a72ed4c4fd64811f9a58f06151810acf/extensions/typescript-language-features/package.json#L705). You could work around this by defining a custom problem matcher that reuses the problem *pattern* [from the TS extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/9878edb2a72ed4c4fd64811f9a58f06151810acf/extensions/typescript-language-features/package.json#L689):

```json
"problemMatcher": [
    {
        "pattern": "$tsc",
        "applyTo": "allDocuments"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just go to File->Open File and choose your log file. Visual Studio Code can open any text encoded file although highlighting and other support/convenience features will depend on your downloaded extensions.

If you go to the extension tab (the square on the left-hand side of the editor) and look up "log" you should find a few log related extensions. *Log File Highlighter* might be of use for your debugging.

Comment: When opening the log file, Visual Studio Code just shows me the content of the log file in a new tab but does not recognize that this is the output of tsc and should be used to show the errors in the Problems panel. I would imagine that I somehow need to load the file in the Problems panel to have the desired functionality but cannot seem to do so.

Comment: I believe the problems panel only shows problems of a projected run from that console, so you would have to actually load your Typescript project into VSCode and run it from the terminal there to see errors in the problems panel. I usually just use the bottom of the screen as a terminal (I prefer using git bash) and when I run from there I see all my outputs and errors in the bottom.